# magento custom module showing blank page

Tags: magento

I have developed a custom magento module for admin section that is working fine on my development server. When I tried to install this module on other server then it is not working properly, when I clicked on module form menu option it is showing blank page. However,
enable/disable option in the advanced configuration is visible.

There are no error getting displayed. How should I debug it? where could be possible bug?

Please help!

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

1. You cant find bugs at your server error log file (ex: /var/log/apache2/error.log).
2. find in you magento index.php this code

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    }

    #ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and change it to

```
    #if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    #}

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Why on earth would you disable that check?  Just configure your web server to set the MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE environment variable.  In Apache this is as simple as "SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE"

Comment: Thanks Nick! I have resolved the issue. It was related to xml file which I need to put in layout folder.

Comment: @Nick - What I mean is, why edit the code and possibly commit your change to your repo (you are using version control, right? lol).  Instead, use the env var like it was meant to be used.  That way, you have the exact same code on production/testing/staging/whatever and the difference is in the web server config.

Answer (score 0):

A blank page generally means a fatal error.  You need to either check your web server error log or PHP error log depending on your setup.

Comment: Thank you very much Lee. I have resolved the issue. This was related to xml file which was required to render layout.